# Как записать NAN в файл?

Tags: c++, файлы

Нужно вписать в файл такое значение, чтобы c++ воспринимал его как NAN при чтении с файла.

Comment: Файл текстовый или бинарный?

Comment: @Chorkov текстовый

Comment: тогда со стандартными потоками - никак. Только читать из потока строку и разбирать самому.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11420263/is-it-possible-to-read-infinity-or-nan-values-using-input-streams

Comment: scanf может прочесть NaN и Inf.

Comment: @Ddd, да, а fprintf соответственно может записать `nan` или `inf`